# Apache ActiveMQ configuration

Tags: java, node.js, message-queue, activemq-classic

I'm working on a project in which I need to produce messages from node.js and consume them using a Java class. But the problem is node.js uses stomp as a client to pub/sub message queue. And stomp uses its own protocol instead of using TCP. On the other hand, the Java client uses TCP for it.

Can we set two transportConnectors for one broker? For Example:

```
<transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://localhost:61613"/>
    </transportConnectors>

    <transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616"/>
    </transportConnectors>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add two transport connector instances, like so:

```
<transportConnectors>
    <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://localhost:61613"/>
    <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

STOMP is actually using TCP/IP just as OpenWire is FYI.

Comment: Thanks it is solved now. i tried the way you told its working now.